# Usage of a priori

Tags: meaning

Can you tell me please if usage of "a priori" in this manner is correct?

> Despite the fact that the numbers point to Iberostar Tenerife as a clear favorite, ***a priori***, to win the derby today, Txus Vidorreta, coach of the Aurinegro team, does not trust the bad moment that Herbalife is going through.

And

> Monchi: “If you ask me if there is a favorite (team), ***a priori*** it is Manchester.

Comment: Is this gambling terminology? I've never heard 'priori' used that way in plain English. It means the probable result of something, maybe even a foregone conclusion. With your use of parenthetic commas it seems like you're *defining* the word.

Comment: @Astralbee yeah, that's what I mean by a priori, as you said, foregone conclusion, for example: "Why do you a priori consider him a criminal?" (Not only gambling terminology)

Comment: @Boyep - because I have seen his police record. You should realise that Latin phrases like a priori, pari passu, inter alia, etc are very unusual indeed in informal English.

Comment: Philosophically, this is an incorrect use of "a priori", which relates to decisions based on logic or theoretical reasoning rather than on evidence, experience, or observation. Your argument is based on evidence and experience, but you mean that it's taking a wide or general view and not focusing on the particulars. If you are wanting to use language strictly you are probably better using something like "generally" or "in the large" or "taking a long-term view", although it would be common in less formal contexts to use something like "in theory".

Comment: @StuartF Ok what about second example? Opponent obviously stronger and more experienced than opposite one and for this reason they are a priori favorite

Answer (score 3):

*A priori* is a Latin phrase used, as an adjective, mostly in philosophy, or the discussion of reasoning, and means:

> using facts or principles that are known to be true in order to decide
> what the likely effects or results of something will be, for example
> saying ‘They haven’t eaten anything all day so they must be hungry.’

It is a formal phrase and not likely to be appropriate in sports journalism. In the examples given in the question, it is used incorrectly. It is not a grand way of saying 'very probably' or 'definitely'.

[A priori (Oxford Learner's Dictionary)](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/a-priori)

Comment: But wiki dictionary says "Self-evident, intuitively obvious".

Comment: @Boyep - use a better dictionary. The outcomes of sporting contests are not logically predictable.